# input from a file using get line

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I am trying to read from a file, and I have separated them by a new line character. I am using these code :

```
fstream input("wordfile.dat", ios::in);

char b[10];

while (!input.eof())
{
    input.getline(b, 10);
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

If I change the loop statement from while(!input.eof()) to while(input) , the program will output a blank line before the loop ends. But now it won't. The question is, in both statements the while condition must first input a line and by inputting it, it will know if it has reached end of file or if there is still more information. So input.eof() must act just like the other statement and output a blank line. First I thought it was a mistake, but I wondered why it was acting correctly. What is the difference between these two conditions?

Comment: Both loops are wrong. `while (input.getline(b, 10)) cout << b << endl;` is the correct way to do it. You cannot rely on testing for end of file *before* you read. The C++ library doesn't know when you are at the end of file. input.eof() is only true when you have tried to read and failed becuse you *were* at the end of file. In other words input.eof() should be used (if you are going to use it at all) after you read not before. It's because of issues like this that you get an extra blank line. Just write the loop as I showed and you'll be fine.

Comment: yes i know they are wrong , when i was reading the code i notice that the loop is wrong , but the result was not wrong.seems like that the eof() , consider next character in the file or something like that , cause eof() does not output blank line ! while(input) , output a blank line. their output must be same , i wonder why their output is different , and one output a blank line , while other do not

Comment: Your versions of the loop will work if the last line in your file does not end with a newline, because then reading the last line does cause input.eof() to be true (or input to be false). input.eof() does *not* consider the next character in the file. It only consideres what has happened in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`operator bool`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) we see ...

> Notice that this function does not return the same as member `good` [...]

... that `if (stream)` is *not* the same as `if (stream.good())`, but also learn that it ...

> Returns whether an error flag is set (either `failbit` or `badbit`).

So it's basically the same as `not stream.fail()` (which is `true` if either `failbit` or `badbit` is set).
This also explains the different behavior between `while (stream)` and `while (not stream.eof())`:

When the input file does not end with a newline, then `stream.getline(buffer, size)` will encounter the end of file before reaching the delimiting newline character (or the 10 character limit) and thus set the `eofbit`. Testing the stream with its `operator bool` will then be still true (since neither `failbit` nor `badbit` are set), and only after trying to read more using `getline` will set the `failbit` since no characters are extracted.

But when testing with `not stream.eof()`, the `eofbit` alone will end the loop.

---

If the stream is `good`, <s>which is what you're testing with,</s>

```
if (stream) // ...
```

then, this means that the stream is neither at the end of file (`eof`), nor `bad` nor `fail`ed.

So when it's not at the end of file, then it could still have failed or be in a bad state.

See [the table here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/).

When reading (or writing) a stream, test for `good` unless you have a specific reason not to do so.

As a side note, this happens when you do input like the following, since `getline` returns a reference to the instance it's called on:

```
while (stream.getline(buffer, size)) {
  // ..
}
```

Comment: in this case , both must have same result , but their results are not same, though stream.good(), results same as stream.eof().but while(stream) do not.

Comment: I found the mistake: I assumed `stream.good()` is the same as `static_cast<bool>(stream)`, which is not true.